# event listener on script tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, async-await

I created CSE (custom search engine)

```
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=f2bcbf82e6df34220">
</script>
<div class="gcse-search"></div>
```

I tried to execute everything using js so I created this code

```
async function clickFirstSearchResult() {
  // Get a reference to the input element by its ID
  var inputElement = document.getElementById("gsc-i-id1");

  // Check if the input element exists on the page
  if (inputElement) {
    // Set the text you want to type into the input element
    var searchText = "newsze99.blogspot.com";

    // Simulate typing by dispatching input events with each character
    for (var i = 0; i < searchText.length; i++) {
      var char = searchText.charAt(i);
      var event = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });
      inputElement.value += char;
      inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    // Get a reference to the search button by its class name
    var searchButton = document.querySelector(".gsc-search-button.gsc-search-button-v2");

    // Check if the search button exists on the page
    if (searchButton) {
      // Trigger a click event on the search button
      searchButton.click();
    }

    // Wait for a short period (adjust as needed) to ensure the search results load
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); // Adjust the delay as needed

    // Now, fetch the value (href) inside the first search result link
    var firstSearchResultLink = document.querySelector(".gs-title a");

    // Check if the first search result link exists on the page
    if (firstSearchResultLink) {
      var linkHref = firstSearchResultLink.getAttribute("data-cturl");

      // Open the link in a new tab
      window.open(linkHref, "_blank");
    }
  }
}

// Call the function to start the process
clickFirstSearchResult();
```

When this js executed in console of browser it type query in search box hit enter and click on first link as I expected.
But when I used this with in my HTML code it didn't work.

My HTML code

This HTML may only work on live server so try this on W3School because it did not work on HTML file in my system

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gcse-search"></div>


  <script>
    // Define a function to execute after the initial script loads
    function executeAfterScriptLoad() {
      async function clickFirstSearchResult() {
        // Get a reference to the input element by its ID
        var inputElement = document.getElementById("gsc-i-id1");

        // Check if the input element exists on the page
        if (inputElement) {
          // Set the text you want to type into the input element
          var searchText = "newsze99.blogspot.com";

          // Simulate typing by dispatching input events with each character
          for (var i = 0; i < searchText.length; i++) {
            var char = searchText.charAt(i);
            var event = new Event("input", {
              bubbles: true
            });
            inputElement.value += char;
            inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);
          }

          // Get a reference to the search button by its class name
          var searchButton = document.querySelector(".gsc-search-button.gsc-search-button-v2");

          // Check if the search button exists on the page
          if (searchButton) {
            // Trigger a click event on the search button
            searchButton.click();
          }

          // Wait for a short period (adjust as needed) to ensure the search results load
          await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); // Adjust the delay as needed

          // Now, fetch the value (href) inside the first search result link
          var firstSearchResultLink = document.querySelector(".gs-title a");

          // Check if the first search result link exists on the page
          if (firstSearchResultLink) {
            var linkHref = firstSearchResultLink.getAttribute("data-cturl");

            // Open the link in a new tab
            window.open(linkHref, "_blank");
          }
        }
      }


      // Create a script element for the provided script
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=f2bcbf82e6df34220"; // Replace with the actual URL of the provided script
      script.onload = function() {
        // The provided script has finished loading, execute your function
        clickFirstSearchResult();
      };

      // Append the script element to the document
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }

    // Wait for the page to finish loading
    window.addEventListener("load", executeAfterScriptLoad);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is showing an error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Comment: Please review [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem" and [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

the script you are trying to add to the header takes a little time to load and get executed even after the `onload` event because it has so much work to do. so you have to put the `clickFirstSearchResult();` call inside a `setTimeout`

```js
script.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(clickFirstSearchResult, 1000)
};
```

or you can also check every 10 milliseconds that is the input in the dom or not. if it is, run the script:

```
function waitFor(id, callback){
    var interval;

    function check(){
        if(document.getElementById(id)) {
            clearInteval(interval);
            callback();
        }
    }

    check();
    interval = setInterval(check, 10)
 }

waitFor("gsc-i-id1", clickFirstSearchResult)
```